# Change direction of outlook sent email to be from right to left in python

Tags: python, outlook, arabic, win32com, office-automation

I want to send arabic email using python through `win32com`, but I want to change the direction of text to be from Right to left in the outlook like in the picture [right to left direction in outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7FWR.png)

Is there a way to do that through the code ?

here is my code

```
    import win32com.client as win32
    from pathlib import Path

    dataframe1 = dataframe.active
    olapp = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
    olns = olapp.GetNameSpace('MAPI')

    arabic_msg_file = Path('arabic_body.txt')

    mail_item = olapp.CreateItem(0)
    mail_item.CC = 'sender@gamil.com'
    mail_item.To = 'receiver@gamil.com'

    mail_item.BodyFormat = 1
    mail_item.Subject = 'subject'
    mail_item.Body = arabic_msg_file.read_text(encoding='utf-8')
    mail_item.Send()
```

Comment: @СергейКох
this the whole code, simply I want to change the direction to be from right to left  instead being left to right, I think It is very clear

Comment: I am not totally sure how this differs from "right justifying" the text? Do you want the text to read from right->left in the email when it arrives at the recipient? The first issue may be that your have set `BodyFormat=1`, which is plain text. I don't think that mode has the concept of left or right justification. You may need HTML or Rich Text?

Comment: @DS_London
I want as you said to make the email read form right to left at the recipient

Comment: @DS_London
If you try to send outlook email using the application or the website, you will have the ability to change the direction of text, so what I want is to control that in the code

Comment: @AbdallahEldesouky If I send an email as Plain Text, the direction is lost in the received mail. I can format R->L in the editor and the text displays that way, but that information is lost before it arrives at the other end. You may need to display the email first (with either a RTF or HTML format), and then use the WordEditor to format the paragraph. This link may be a starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.getinspector?source=recommendations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on what I suggested in the comments, here is one possible solution. I've replaced the reading of the text file with some dummy text lines.

```
import win32com.client as wc

ol = wc.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application')

text = 'Broad is the Gate and wide the Path\n' 
text += 'That leads man to his daily bath.\n'
text += 'But \'ere you spend the shining hour,\n'
text += 'With plunge and spray, with sluice and shower,\n'
text += 'Remember, whereso\'er you be,\n'
text += 'To shut the door and turn the key!\n'

item = ol.CreateItem(wc.constants.olMailItem)#=0

item.To = 'xxx@yyy.com'
item.Subject = 'Test email formatting'
item.Body = text
item.BodyFormat = wc.constants.olFormatHTML #=2

item.Display()

#Either explicitly cast to the Word Document interface
doc = wc.CastTo(item.GetInspector.WordEditor,'_Document')
doc.Paragraphs.ReadingOrder = wc.constants.wdReadingOrderRtl #=0

#Or use the 'magic number' for the reading order
#doc = item.GetInspector.WordEditor
#doc.Paragraphs.ReadingOrder = 0

item.Send()
```

This is what arrives at the Recipient's end:

[image]

Notes:

1. I haven't found a way to be able to Send without Display-ing first. Maybe some other SO member can suggest a way? `Send()` throws a `The parameter is incorrect` exception if `Display()` has not been called previously.
2. I am not a fan of 'magic numbers' replacing constants, hence I have used the `gencache` route for creating objects, and `CastTo` to generate the constants for the Word Document interface. If you want to stick with simple `Dispatch()` then I have included the magic numbers for the constants. Using the constants makes it easier to port VBA code to Python.

**But an alternative and simpler approach** is to turn the text into HTML first:

```
import win32com.client as wc

ol = wc.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application')

text = 'Broad is the Gate and wide the Path\n' 
text += 'That leads man to his daily bath.\n'
text += 'But \'ere you spend the shining hour,\n'
text += 'With plunge and spray, with sluice and shower,\n'
text += 'Remember, whereso\'er you be,\n'
text += 'To shut the door and turn the key!\n'
   
item = ol.CreateItem(wc.constants.olMailItem)#=0

item.To = 'xxx@yyy.com'
item.Subject = 'Test email formatting'

item.BodyFormat = wc.constants.olFormatHTML #=1
item.HTMLBody = "<p dir=RTL style='text-align:right;direction:rtl'><span dir=LTR>" + text.replace('\n','<br>') + "</span></p>"
   
item.Send()
```

I am not familiar with how punctuation works in Arabic script, so you may need to play around with the HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

The plain text body format doesn't allow setting up any formatting, nor provides any options for specifying the layout:

```
mail_item.BodyFormat = 1
mail_item.Body = arabic_msg_file.read_text(encoding='utf-8')
```

Note, you can use the Word object model for setting up the message body in the way you need. The `WordEditor` property of the `Inspector` class returns an instance of the Word `Document` class where you can set up the [ParagraphFormat.Alignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.paragraphformat.alignment) property, for example:

```
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
```